# Ошибка при загрузке изображений WordPress

Tags: wordpress

При попытке загрузить изображение на WordPress выдает ошибку, но при этом изображение сохраняется в директории
В дебаг логе выдает следующее
Aq_Resize.process() error: Image file does not exist (or is not an image:
Что делать?

Comment: Первое - поставить https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ и посмотреть здоровье сайта. Включая серверные/php-шные модули.